# rails/angular ui router issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've been doing a [thinkster tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails) on combining rails and angular. I've been doing it steadily, but have been halted by an issue with the ui.router. The moment I place ['ui.router'] into my angular module it messes up my page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Flapper News</h1>
        </div>

          <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)">^</span>
              {{ post.upvotes }}
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
            <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
              {{ post.title}}
            </a>
            <span ng-hide="post.link">
              {{ post.title }}
            </span>
          </div>

          <form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px">
            <h3>Add a new post</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link"></input>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Post</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>

angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.factory("posts", [function(){
var o = {
posts: []
};
  return o;
}])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
 "posts",
function($scope, posts){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
  $scope.posts = posts.posts;
  $scope.posts = [
    {title: "post 1", upvotes: 5},
    {title: "post 2", upvotes: 2},
    {title: "post 3", upvotes: 15},
    {title: "post 4", upvotes: 9},
    {title: "post 5", upvotes: 4}
  ];
  $scope.addPost = function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === "") {return; }
    $scope.posts.push({
      title: $scope.title,
      link: $scope.link,
      upvotes: 0
    });
    $scope.title = "";
    $scope.link = "";
  };
   $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
    post.upvotes += 1;
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, that you already have the module `flapperNews` declared, and you are loosing the dependencies that where previously added. Check if elswehere (maybe in `app.js`) you have another code like this:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', [/** other deps**/]);
```

If you have it, just add `ui.router` to that module declaration.

Remember that if you pass a second parameter to `angular.module`, you will declare/redeclare that module. If you only pass the first parameter, the method will act as a getter and retreive the module.